# Do While loop gets stuck

Tags: java, while-loop

The code is a Tic-Tac-Toe game (in progress). When I run the code it asks X's position number then it stops. It has to do with the while loop because when I run it without it it works fine. I need the loop however to set X as false so it changes to O's turn.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class TicTacToe


{
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int XInput, OInput;
    boolean IfGameOver;
    String []board = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
    IfGameOver = false;
    boolean Xturn, Oturn;
    Xturn = true;
    Oturn = false;

    System.out.print("Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe!\n\n");
do
    {

        {
         System.out.println(" " + board[0] + board[1] + board[2]);
         System.out.println(" " + board[3] + board[4] + board[5]);
         System.out.println(" " + board[6] + board[7] + board[8]);
        }
             if (Xturn)
             System.out.println("It is X's turn, position number?");
             if (Oturn)
             System.out.println("It is O's turn, position number?");

            do
                {
                try
                {
                XInput = scan.nextInt();
                board[XInput-1] = "X";
                Oturn= true;
                Xturn = false;
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a position number");
                    XInput = scan.nextInt();
                }
                }while(Xturn = true);
            do
                {
                try
                {
                OInput = scan.nextInt();
                board[OInput-1] = "X";
                Oturn = false;
                Xturn = true;
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a position number");
                    OInput = scan.nextInt();
                }
                }while (Oturn = true);

    } while (!IfGameOver);
}
}
```

Comment: *"run it without it it"* - too many pronouns!

Comment: You might want to remove the second `scan.nextInt()` in your catch statements since you'd be asking for input twice in a row.

Comment: I would suggest, you take the user input loop and move it to its own method, this way you can reduce the complexity a little further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple issues.  As stated previously, your not using an equality check in your while statement, but the other issues override this one.  You are setting Oturn to true after X's turn but prior to your do-while loop for O's turn.  Therefore, you are going into the Oturn do loop immediately following X input.  This should clean it up...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class TicTacToe

{
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Input;
    boolean IfGameOver;
    String []board = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
    IfGameOver = false;
    boolean Xturn = true;

    System.out.print("Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe!\n\n");
do
    {

        {
         System.out.println(" " + board[0] + board[1] + board[2]);
         System.out.println(" " + board[3] + board[4] + board[5]);
         System.out.println(" " + board[6] + board[7] + board[8]);
        }
             if (Xturn)
             System.out.println("It is X's turn, position number?");
             else
             System.out.println("It is O's turn, position number?");

             Input = -1;
            do
                {
                try
                {
                Input = scan.nextInt();
                board[Input-1] = (Xturn?"X":"O");
                Xturn = !Xturn;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a valid position number");
                }
                }while(Input==-1);
    } while (!IfGameOver);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely on this line:

```
            }while(Xturn = true);
```

This is not a comparison. The `=` operator is *assignment*. This assigns the value `true` to `Xturn`, and then continues the loop because the result of an assignment is always the value that is assigned.

For comparison, you would use `==`. But since `Xturn` is a boolean to start with, you can write simply:

```
            }while(Xturn);
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes i did :s

Comment: @JustinBeaubien: That may not be the only error in your code; I have not inspected it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
}while(Xturn = true);
...
}while (Oturn = true);
```

to

```
}while(Xturn);
...
}while (Oturn);
```

`Xturn = true` is an assignment and won't check to see if `Xturn` is true. In order to do that, you must use `Xturn == true` or simple `Xturn`. The same goes for `Oturn`.

Also, as stated by [TAsk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29980659/3943044), you need the value of `IfGameOver` to become true inside the loop in order for the code to exit the outer `do while` loop.